# Record User Input and translate to text iPhone

Tags: ios, core-audio

I'm using the maluuba API ([Malubba Dev Site](http://dev.maluuba.com/)), a natural language processing API but they don't mention anywhere in their documentation of how to turn the sounds the user says into the microphone into actual text. Is that something that CoreAudio can do? If so, how would I implement that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing (currently or publicly) in Core Audio that does continuous speech recognition into text.  (Siri reportedly works by compressing some recorded audio input and sending it to Apple's, or previously Nuance's, servers for recognition and processing into a query).

Core audio is useful for the recording portion of this.

An open source project that attempts to do speech recognition on iOS is OpenEars, using CMU's PocketSphinx technology.  Reports vary as to the quality of the results.  You might also try contacting Nuance to see if they might license use of their speech recognition API for a price.